# Unable to update In-App-Products in Google Play Console

Tags: android, google-play, google-play-console

I've been trying to update my In-App-Prodcuts prices in Google Play Console for 2 days now and I'm still stuck with the following error message when trying to import a `*.csv`

```
You need to set your product's price for following countries: Myanmar (Burma) (MM), Paraguay (PY), Serbia (RS).
```

I cannot find either of the countries. Not in the prices list nor in the Pricing&Distribution subpage.

Google support won't reply to my messages.

Is anyone aware of this issue and could provide a workaround?

Thanks.

Comment: Similar problem here updating a subscription. It seems a bug, some weeks ago we've changed them without any problem. Sorry, no workaround found.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Magically, all countries suddenly appeared.

Apparently, you just have to wait long enough. Google support replied to my question telling me to update the prices for the missing countries :-/ That was also very helpful since the point was that I didn't see them! Anyway, still less pain than iTunes Connect.

Answer (score 0):

Hi Please read below official google play billing doc for update prices.

https://developer.android.com/google/play/billing/billing_subscriptions

if you are using subscriptions than and only than you can changed the prices of in-app product. Hope this helps you.

Comment: doesn't help at all, but thanks anyway. Prices of in-app-products can be changed at any time, the issue I'm facing is that I'm supposed to define prices for countries that I don't even see in the list. That's either a bug or very well hidden in the Google Play Console.

Comment: @marco.eig you cann't changed price on country wise. I think you can enter price based on country and currency calculations are automatically converted by google play console.

Comment: The problem is that they tell me to enter a price for Serbia, Myanmar, and Paraguay but I cannot see it on the list. Even if I try to import the same CSV that I exported a second ago I get the same error.

Answer (score 0):

It seems is a browser dependent bug, I've just tried with Chrome and works fine. The problem was in Safari.

Comment: I tried it using Chrome, Firefox, Safari on Mac and Chrome, Firefox, Edge on Windows. I always get the same error message. This is so stupid. They tell me to enter prices for Myanmar, Serbia, and Paraguay but don't provide it in the list. And Google support hasn't cared to reach out to me either.

Answer (score 0):

Keep your price above 0.20 USD as google in-app preference is only available for 0.20 USD price of your product. And remove the incoming error

Comment: If you app use CAD then choose 0.26 CAD

Answer (score 0):

I ran into this issue and the workaround was to:

1. export the data CSV
2. try to upload the exported data CSV, which doesn't work
3. take note of the countries that are missing, e.g. EC, FM, GI, IN, ...

[image]

4. open the data CSV
5. manually patch the end of the price list the missing countries and prices - in my case I used an arbitrary number of 200 AUD, converted it to their local currency, then multiply by 1 million e.g. today, `200 AUD = 11,109.54 INR` multiplied by 1 million is `11109540000`

```
// Price list currently shows:
"AU; 12190000; AE; 31990000; AT; 9490000; AU; 11990000; ..."
// Add to the end of that same cell my arbitrary prices:
"... ; IN; 11109540000; LK; 46805570000; MM; 284078660000; OM; 51990000"
```

6. Upload the edited CSV, which should work
7. Double check and edit pricing inside the Google Play Console (in my case I just recalculated all of the local prices)